# Is there any way to target siblings with `withStyles` in Material ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am using the Select component of material ui. I want to customise the dropdown menu with a top arrow. I have overriden `menuStyle` using pseudo element `before`. However, the arrow appears on the screen even before clicking on the dropdown. This is because the class is used in select element as well. I want to target dropdown menu by checking for the siblings.

```
         <Select
              value={this.state.date}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              displayEmpty
              name='date'
              autoWidth={false}
              className={classes.selectWithArrow}
              classes={{
                icon: classes.icon,
                selectMenu: classes.menuStyle,
                select: classes.select,
              }}
              renderValue={value => this.state.date}
              root={classes.root}
              input={
                <Input
                  name='date'
                  id="label-placeholder"
                  classes={{
                    root: classes.root,
                  }}
                />
              }
              MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: classes.menuStyle } }}
            >
              <MenuItem value={1}>One</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={2}>Two</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={3}>Three</MenuItem>
         </Select>
```

I want to target siblings something like this -

```
  const styles = theme => ({

   '.menuStyle.selectMenu': {

    '&::before': {

      },
    }
  });
```

Is there any way? Any leads will be highly appreciated.